Async Api: Generate Java Client using Schema Registry and AVRO messages
I´m using Confluent Async Api Tool to export the topic / schema definitions to an async-api.yml file.
I want to generate a Spring Cloud Client using Schema Registry and AVRO generated classes from the schema associated with the topic, but the async api generator tool doesn´t works with the Confluent Schema Registry and AVRO schemas
How can i generate a Java (Spring if possible) client for this async-api file (using Schema Registry and AVRO)?
A tool or a way to generate a client automatically from the async-api.yml using the schema registry and AVRO for encoding

can you please share the errors you're getting from the generator

There aren´t errors... the template is generating the project. The java beans generated by the template are using jackson to serialize the object instead of AVRO generated classes. I supose that the template should save the schema and use the maven AVRO plugin to generate the classes instead...

oh, ok, so generator actually works with schema registry and avro.
you just do not like that Avro schema is converted into JSON Schema for code generation purposes.
here you have more details: https://github.com/asyncapi/avro-schema-parser
the conversion needs to take place, so code generators do not need to now understand all schema formats like Avro or protobuf, but just work with JSON Schema.

you could open an issue in https://github.com/asyncapi/avro-schema-parser/issues and suggest that avro is still somehow preserved. But then check with maintainers of https://github.com/asyncapi/java-spring-cloud-stream-template if they want to support code generation from Avro and why it is important
